# OverridePendingTransition doesnt work if i will use intent

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm trying to open an already activity with animation open.

It will run it only first time which `activity` starts and then it will not work again

**Here is the code :**

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TableItemsMain))
                 .SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
    StartActivity(intent);
    OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Layout.trans_left_in, Resource.Layout.trans_left_out);
```

Comment: In which method there is your OverridePendingTransition?

Comment: Please provide complete codes or a basic sample that can reproduce the issue.